# Remove the size request of a widget (Python, Gtk3)

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to fit some text in a label. I almost managed to do it: when I enlarge the window, I add some `<big>` tags to the label and the text enlarges with the window. But if I try to shrink the window, the size-request of the label doesn't let me do it.

The label is updated many times a second, so if I try to set a custom size request every time I apply a new label, the window will shrink and enlarge if i try to shrink it.

What I want to do is removing the size request, without word wrapping and other things like this: I just want let the label go out of the window.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provided a minimal code. But in general you should avoid setting size-requests and instead let the widget expand and fill in its parent container. If you must do manual size-requests for some reason, you could use -1 for the dimension that you wish remove the manual request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "ellipsize" property of label to True.

Answer (score 1):

Put the label in a container like GtkScrolledWindow.

Comment: But I don't want it to be scrolled! I just want it to fit the window!
Thanks for your answer! ;)